# Is there way to calculate or query 'finish_lsn' of failing logical subscription in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, subscriber, logical-replication

In Postgres when logical replication is hanging on conflict you can read pending WAL entries and see which row is conflicting as well as check LSN of that transaction using `pg_logical_slot_peek_changes`.

There is possibility to skip failing LSN but in order to achieve that you must check Postgres logs in order to find `finish_lsn` like this one:

> CONTEXT:  processing remote data for replication origin "pg_41805" during message type "INSERT" for replication target relation "Schema.Table" in transaction 43436, finished at 0/37571918

This `finish_lsn` differs from transaction LSN which you can check using `pg_logical_slot_peek_changes`. It is always a bit behind it. And it seems consistent per database which is source like always 56 (lets call it position slots in WAL behind). When you setup replication for different DB than number is different.

Is there any function that can calculate this `finish_lsn` or any formula how to calculate it ? So we can use skip LSN without access to Postgres logs ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this using SQL. You could use `log_destination = 'csvlog'` and a file_fdw foreign table to `SELECT` from the log. That way, you could extract the required information. But do you really want to skip replication conflicts automatically?

Comment: [`select pg_read_file(pg_current_logfile());`](https://dbfiddle.uk/jay-Ewpa)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thnx for your comments, 

I'm currently developing built-in support for logical replication in my microservice core library. Goal is that end developer can express in his c# code which tables he wishes to replicate and which not also more complex scenarios like filters, replica identity and etc. 

I'm also adding alerting based on detection of replication lag and stopped on conflict subscriptions.  

So I'm building my maintenance API helping in such situations by allowing to query status of such subscription/publication.

Comment: Additionaly option to view conflicting transaction and skip failing LSN (in case developer behind microservice will consider this safe operation). 

This is exposed to end user though our API behind our authorization so there is no need to connect to DB for end developer. I'm looking for reasonable way to calculate this finish_lsn without need to reach to logs. It is odd we are able to check LSN of failling transaction but this not the one that will allow us to skip it.

Comment: I've tried to find in Postgres code but failed to grasp it in reasonable time. So I was hoping someone tried it before me.

Most important for me is that this solution can not affect DB performance. In case it will not be possible I will leave developers need to perform logs search (kibana/elastic) for this particular case.

Comment: I'd say that this is a missing feature. It should be possible to add that information to `pg_stat_subscription` or `pg_stat_subscription_stats`. Skipping transactions is a fairly new feature, so it may well not be feature complete. You could write a patch for PostgreSQL or pay someone to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any function that can calculate this finish_lsn or any formula how to calculate it ?

There is not.

> Is there way to calculate **or query 'finish_lsn'** of failing logical subscription in Postgres

There is:

```sql
select pg_read_file(pg_current_logfile());
```

It's a bit of a stretch: is it a query? Yes. Does it return `finish_lsn`? If it's in the log, it will - along with everything else in there, unless you narrow it down a bit with `offset` and `length` parameters, or pass it straight into [`regexp_substr()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to [pinpoint](https://dbfiddle.uk/oRIyhBMw) the target line. So technically, it sort of satisfies your initial criteria, but fails to meet the criteria of not needing to look in the Postgres logs. Still, it *does* save you the trip out of your `psql` terminal.

If you're operating under anything else than a role with `superuser` attribute, you'll need to `grant execute` on [`pg_read_file()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#id-1.5.8.33.11.6.2.2.9.1.1.1) and [`pg_current_logfile()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.3.4.2.2.14.1.1.1).

---

A pretty controversial approach would be to iterate over LSNs around what you get from peeking, trying to skip each one: the skip works only if the txn will be the first one to come in after preparing the skip and trying to resume subscription. If it's anything else, Postgres will again receive and attempt to apply the conflicting operation again (it'll differ from `pg_subscription.subskiplsn` so it won't try to skip it), then fail again, at which point you can guess again.

Comment: Hi @Zergarek, thnx for your answer but this not what I'm looking for. I've got those logs in Elasticsearch if I would go with logs I would look for them there. I'm hoping for some option to calculate it at least. If I will not find any option that will not affect DB performance I will than leave devs with manual search for this log entry than as in comment above.

Comment: @Ciapeczka Sure, you did clearly specify what you're looking for. The sad, repeated answer is, it's not implemeneted (yet) - this post merely confirms that you do need a workaround, and at the absence of any additional details of your setup, offered two examples limited to in-db context, since Postgres was the only element you disclosed.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you you are looking for, but you can also parse Postgres logs and extract the `finish_lsn` for a specific transaction using a `Perl` script  (with good performance in server side)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
 
my $log_file = "/path/to/postgresql/logfile";
my $transaction_id = 111111;
 
open(LOG, "<", $log_file) or die "Failed to open log file: $!";

# Loop through each line
while (<LOG>) {
  # Search for lines containing the transaction ID and "finished at" message
  if (/(\d+): (\d+) finished at \d+\/\d+/) {
    my ($pid, $lsn) = ($1, $2);
    # Check if transaction ID matches
    if ($pid eq $transaction_id) {
      print "Finish LSN for transaction $transaction_id: $lsn\n";
      close(LOG);
      exit 0;
    }
  }
}

print "Finish LSN not found for transaction $transaction_id\n";
close(LOG);
```

Comment: It turned out they're [fed to Elastisearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78045660/is-there-way-to-calculate-or-query-finish-lsn-of-failing-logical-subscription/78101042#comment137635544_78070267), so if OP were to search them, their preference is to do that there. That search can also be done directly on that db with what I showed: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oRIyhBMw), which means you technically *can* set it up as the function OP wanted and call it right in the [``pg_replication_origin_advance()``](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersubscription.html#id-1.9.3.33.6).